# Comments as a block

Tags: 7, comments

I need to display the comments for a node as a block. For drupal 6 there the [comment block](http://drupal.org/project/commentblock) module but it's not available for drupal 7 as well.

It there a way to achieve the same functionality in drupal 7 or I'll have to build a custom module for this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to display comments associated with a node. No coding required.

Comment: yeah, I know that. But the comments are also visible on the node page itself, after the node body. I need to remove those... So I will have to use `hook_node_view_alter()` for that

Answer (score 1):

[Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module will give you a solution

Comment: With Panels you can "recreate" the node display page then separate body from node comments on different layout areas.